# Unity animation property stays disabled if input is being spammed

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am currently working on first basic features of my game and this one scratches my head. I want to achieve simple thing: box collider activating only on selected frames of my attack animation to deal damage and then being disabled once attack animation is done. To achieve that I am using properties in Animation window. I have set it up so that on first frame of an attack collider becomes active and on last frame of animation it returns to disabled state.

This seems to be working in simple cases of isolated attack button presses. However if I spam direction inputs and attack, I have quite frequent situation where all property manipulation stops working for some reason (collider stays disabled) until i stop pressing any buttons for some time.

I have tried to debug it on my own. I have removed all logic concerning Collider itself from the code (that is why it will be in wrong place in GIF) also I have moved Collider enable key frame in every frame of animation. Both of these did not work.

[image: Here is a link to see how my animations are set up.]

[Here is short clip how collider stops working after simple input.](https://i.gyazo.com/161f8e944734ace63383d2ddafe4cd4a.mp4)

I had similar expiriences with animation events in previous game I was working on. This time event disabling collider was not firing sometimes.

I know how to work around this - I can get animation duration and then enable/disable collider using Time.deltaTime, but I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Currently it seems to me that property manipulation via Animation seems extremaly unreliable and as I don't have a lot of expirience in Unity it is probably me not knowing something instead of API fault. So can someone answer what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add all required information (e.g. about your state machine and how you enter/leave animations) and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sorry for late response and not adding all required information. There was no code attached to this behavior, so that is why I have not added any, but should have added animation state machine - cause that was the issue after all. I was able to figure it out on my own and I am coming back with details if someone will encounter similar behavior in future.

**Short answer:** if you are using events tied to animation frames, make sure that these frames are playing in your game :)

**Long answer:** I was actually using Blend trees for movement and attack - as quick test on how they actually work. Last week I was reworking my animation, after realizing that using blend trees for attack is not suitable for my case. It is during this process that I have realized that if I spam attack, its animation will not be able to play key frames that enable and reenable the trigger. Fix is of course really easy: set exit time and fixed duration - during transition out of attacking state. In addition I have also freezed attack for animation duration to avoid spam. And voila! Everything works now :).